# I want to chang image of button. when I click image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to change the image of a button to another image when clicked.

I know about `setImageResource` method but I don't know how to apply it in this piece of code.

this is my source code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Toolbar extends LinearLayout {

public Toolbar(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Toolbar(final Context con, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(con,attrs);       
    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    setBackgroundColor(getResources().
            getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation, this);

    TypedArray a = con.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, 
            R.styleable.Toolbar);
    String option = a.getString(R.styleable.Toolbar_tab_id);

    String resourceId = "com.paxmodept.demo:id/"+option;
    int optionId = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceId,null,null);              
    TextView currentOption = (TextView) findViewById(optionId);
    currentOption.setBackgroundColor(getResources().
            getColor(android.R.color.black));
    currentOption.setTextColor(getResources().
            getColor(android.R.color.black));
    currentOption.requestFocus(optionId);
    currentOption.setFocusable(false);
    currentOption.setClickable(false);

    TextView tab1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    tab1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(con, Tab1.class);
            con.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    TextView tab2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab2);
    tab2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(con, Tab2.class);
            con.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    TextView tab3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab3);
    tab3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(con, Tab3.class);
            con.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    TextView tab4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab4);
    tab4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(con, Tab4.class);
            con.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

and the XML code:

```
<merge 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab1"
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/backgound_states" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/eventoff" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab2"
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/backgound_states" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/galleryoff" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab3"
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/backgound_states" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/menuoff"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab4"
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/backgound_states" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/strockoff"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center" />

    <!-- android:background="@drawable/contact"  -->
```

Comment: where is button in this layout? I cannot see any button code above..plz  highlight it

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a drawable that will be white by default, black when pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/black" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Define it in the Folder /res/drawable as xml and attach it to your button background. You are able to define this `<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />` also as drawable like
`<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_pic" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
  button.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_bg));
  there is another way to set image
  button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_bg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code whenever you want to change the Image.
btn_instance is tha instance of your button.

```
btn_instance.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_image_ro);
```